# Constructor for array of custom objects in member initializer list

Tags: c++

I have some custom objects, using a simplified example to show the problem I am having

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct DataPoint {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
}

// The goal of this object is to look like a vector but without the 
// dynamic allocation (after initial initialization) hence why I am 
// forcing a constructor like this.
class DataPoints {
public:
  explicit DataPoints(size_t n) : points_(n) {};

private:
  size_t current_size_ = 0;
  std::vector<DataPoint> points_;
};


class DataLayers {
public:
  // Here is where I have the problem, there is no default constructor for DataPoints,
  // and need to initialize layers_ which is an array. I hope to eventually allow 
  // layers_ to be different sizes on initialization and so can't hard code an array
  // initialization
  DataLayers() : 
    // What I would like to do (this does not work) is something like this, and each
    // array element in layers_ gets initialized to a size of 100000;
    layers_(100000),
    // Have also tried 
    layers(DataPoints(100000)) {
  }

private:
  std::array<DataPoints, 10> layers_;
}
```

I have got a temporary work around by setting a default argument in DataPoints

```cpp
DataPoints(size_t n = 100000) // rest of code
```

I would prefer to move the initialization/sizing to Layers since Layers knows more about how many DataPoints it needs.
Is this possible in C++ (using 14).

Comment: Well, can you explain where do you expect the parameter to the constructor to each instance of your `layers_` `DataPoints` instance to come from? It has to come from somewhere.

Comment: "_hope to eventually allow layers_ to be different sizes on initialization and so can't hard code an array initialization_": So you are going to make `layers_` a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array` anyway, and then there won't be any issue. A `std::vector` can always be default-constructed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in this example DataLayers knows it needs 100000 elements.
However in other parts of my code I use different sizes of DataPoints `DataPoints(250)` (for example)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like this. With this, you can write

```
DataLayers() : layers_(make_std_array<DataPoints, 10>(std::size_t(100000))) {}
```

---

```
template <typename T, std::size_t size, typename U, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<T, size> make_std_array_helper(const U& init, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return {(Is, T{init}) ...};
}

template <typename T, std::size_t size, typename U>
std::array<T, size> make_std_array(const U& init) {
  return make_std_array_helper<T, size>(init, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WcnY45bP6)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array<DataPoints, 10> layers_;
```

You have ten `DataPoints` here. Each one is a completely independent object, that has nothing to do with any of the nine instances of `DataPoints`, that happen to live nearby in memory.

Each instance of a `DataPoints` requires an explicit constructor. No matter which way you look, you have ten objects here. Each one needs to be constructed. There's no way to do it with just a single `100000`. That's only good enough to initialize one object, but you need ten of them.

As a result of that, you have no alternatives to constructing every one of these ten instances of `DataPoints`, individually:

```
class DataLayers {
public:
    DataLayers() :
        layers_{{ DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000},
              DataPoints{100000}
        }}
    {
    }
```

Welcome to C++. The rules are very strict, and must be followed to the letter. If `DataPoints`'s constructor was not `explicit` you can reduce the pain, a little bit. If `explicit` gets removed, this can be reduced to:

```
        layers_{{ {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000},
              {100000}
        }}
```

The reason for all these braces has to do with other rules of C++, for which there are no alternatives or shortcuts:

- One set of braces for constructing the `layers` object.
- A `std::array` is a container that contains a single member, the array object, and its aggregate initialization requires its own set of braces.
- Finally each value in the array gets constructed with its own pair of braces.